# Angular 2 Material 2 Sidenav Toolbar collapse like Navigation Drawer

Tags: angular, navigation-drawer, transition, angular-material2

I have a sidenav and a nested toolbar
**toolbar.html**

```
<md-sidenav-container fullscreen>
    <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" color="primary">
     <md-toolbar color="primary"><span>Sidenav</span></md-toolbar>
        <button md-button class="sidenav-link" (click)="sidenav.close()">
          <md-icon>home</md-icon><span class="title"> HOME</span>
          </button>
          <button md-button class="sidenav-link" (click)="sidenav.close()">
            <md-icon>home</md-icon><span class="title"> HOME</span>
          </button>
      </md-sidenav>
      <app-toolbar [sidenav]="sidenav"></app-toolbar>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

**sidenav.html**

```
<md-toolbar color="primary">
  <button md-button class="toolbar-menu-button"
          (click)="sidenav.toggle(); isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
    <md-icon [@iconChange]="isCollapsed">menu</md-icon>
  </button>
  <span class="toolbar-spacer"></span>
  <button md-button class="toolbar-link" >DASHBOARD</button>
  <span class="toolbar-spacer"></span>
</md-toolbar>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/up19ZNJyMt6uatqdI9uv?p=preview

I would like to close the sidenav up to the home icon like Navigation Drawer

**close sidenav**
[image: sidenav close]

**open sidenav**
[image: sidenav open]

Comment: Could you set min-width on sidnav?

Comment: not work. I can not change this  <div cdk-scrollable="" class="mat-sidenav-content" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="margin-left: 320px; margin-right: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">

Comment: You can always set opened="true" so that the drawer is always shown. Then put the text in a span and in this span add an *ngif that gets toggled through button click

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is little unusual. Since the button from toolbar is controlling the open and close state, I had to add an `EventListener` to pass the state of `sidenav` whenever the button is clicked.

Based on the `event` flag, I added some `ngStyle` that will maintain the width of `sidenav`. Note that, the `sidenav` is always open now [add property `opened="true"`], since it's always visible. I also ended up using the emitted flag from toolbar to use for 'Sidenav' title. You can remove it if you need to show the partial 'Sid'.

Also, since the sidenav is always open, I added custom css to animate the change of width.

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ONDk6R5feqqk7ygnUS3H?p=preview)

toolbar.component.ts:

```
export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {

  shortnav = true;

  @Input() sidenav;

  @Output()
  change: EventEmitter<booelan> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor() { 
    console.log(this.sidenav);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  toggle(){
    this.shortnav = !this.shortnav;
    console.log("shortnav: " + this.shortnav)
    this.change.emit(this.shortnav);
  }

}
```

toolbar.component.html:

```
<button md-button class="toolbar-menu-button"
          (click)="toggle(); isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
```

sidenav.component.ts:

```
export class SidenavOverviewExample {

  showSidenavTitle = false;
  sidenavWidth = 2.75;

  changeWidth(showShortNav){
    if(showShortNav){
      this.sidenavWidth = 2.5;
      this.showSidenavTitle = false;
    }
    else{
      this.sidenavWidth = 13;
      this.showSidenavTitle = true;
    }
  }
}
```

sidenav.component.html:

```
<md-sidenav-container fullscreen>
    <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side"   
                color="primary" 
                opened="true"
                [ngStyle]="{ 'width.em': sidenavWidth }"
                class="animate-sidenav">
     <md-toolbar color="primary">
       <span *ngIf="showSidenavTitle">Sidenav</span>
     </md-toolbar>
        <button md-button class="sidenav-link" (click)="sidenav.close()">
          <md-icon>home</md-icon><span class="title"> HOME</span>
          </button>
          <button md-button class="sidenav-link" (click)="sidenav.close()">
            <md-icon>home</md-icon><span class="title"> HOME</span>
          </button>
      </md-sidenav>

      <app-toolbar [sidenav]="sidenav" (change)="changeWidth($event)"></app-toolbar>

 </md-sidenav-container>
```

sidenav.component.css:

```
.mat-sidenav-transition .mat-sidenav{
  /* custom animation to grow and shrink width */
  -webkit-transition: width .3s !important; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width .3s !important;
}
```

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 11):

[image]

This can be achieved using a simple css hack.
We can call methods increase() and decrease() that changes the width of sidenav based on some event like **mouseenter** and **mouseleave** or in your case onClick of **"toolbar-menu-button"**

```
<md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" class="example-sidenav" [ngStyle]="{ 'width.em': sidenavWidth }" opened="true" (mouseover)="increase()"   (mouseleave)="decrease()">
```

This will incerese the width of sidenav when we point on sidenav and decrease the width when we point the mouse pointer at some other place.

```
  increase(){
    this.sidenavWidth = 15;
  }
  decrease(){
    this.sidenavWidth = 4;
  }
```

Have a look at this demo :- https://mini-sidenav.firebaseapp.com/

and the github repo :- https://github.com/Ravi-Rajpurohit/mini-md-sidenav

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: This makes it interesting