# How to impliment a sidenav Navigation drawer with a (Mini variant)

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Angular material 2 community I need your help how to make mini variant like google material design example in angular Material 2.

I try to implement this but I can't make this happen

[image]

#### My code so far

```
  <!-- ===================================================================== -->
  <!-- SIDENAV && SIDENAV CONTAINER -->
  <!-- ===================================================================== -->
  <mat-sidenav-container>

    <mat-sidenav 
      #adminNavMenu 
      mode="side" 
      opened="true"
      style="min-width:50px; background: #F3F3F3;"
      class="shadow_right" autosize>

      <!-- MENU LEFT -->
      <app-admin-menu-left></app-admin-menu-left>

    </mat-sidenav>

   <mat-sidenav-container>
```

#### app-admin-menu-left.html

```
<mat-nav-list style="min-width:60px;">

  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let page of Menus"> 
    <a routerLink="{{page.link}}" routerLinkActive="active" 
      [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" matLine>
      <mat-icon class="home_icon collapse-icon vcenter" mat-list-icon>{{page.icon}}</mat-icon>
      <span *ngIf="!showFiller">
        {{page.name}}
      </span>
    </a>
  </mat-list-item>


</mat-nav-list>

<button  mat-icon-button (click)="showFiller = !showFiller" mat-raised-button>
  <mat-icon *ngIf="!showFiller">chevron_right</mat-icon>
  <mat-icon *ngIf="showFiller">chevron_left</mat-icon> 
</button>
```

#### And gives me this unexpected result

[image: Result screenshoot]

After I click to view the mini bar
[image]

> As you see there is a margin 250 px on `mat-sidenav-content` but I can't access this element.

[image: Google devtools console +review]

Any help to solve this is gonna be useful.

Thanks

Comment: take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405144/angular-2-material-2-sidenav-toolbar-collapse-like-navigation-drawer)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

### I have passed this problem with that solution.

Good luck.

Also, I have made a working example in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8zy3pi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

[image]

### home.component.html

```html
    <div>
    
      <mat-sidenav-container>
    
        <mat-sidenav #adminNavMenu mode="side" opened="true" style="min-width:60px; background: #F3F3F3;" class="shadow_right" autosize>
    
          <!-- MENU LEFT -->
          <app-admin-menu-left></app-admin-menu-left>
    
        </mat-sidenav>
    
        <!-- ================================================================= -->
        <!-- ************************* MAIN CONTAINER ************************ -->
        <!-- ================================================================= -->
        <mat-sidenav-content [@onSideNavChange]="sideNavState">
          <div class="main_container" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="0px" style="height:100vh;">
    
            <!-- =============================================================== -->
            <!-- Your main content -->
            <!-- =============================================================== -->
    
          </div>
        </mat-sidenav-content>
    
      </mat-sidenav-container>
    
    
    </div>
```

### home.component.ts

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material';
    import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/animations';
    
    import { MediatorService } from '@app-services/mediator/mediator.service';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-admin-analytics',
      templateUrl: './admin-analytics.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./admin-analytics.component.css'],
      animations: [
        trigger('onSideNavChange', [
          state('close',
            style({
              'margin-left': '60px'
            })
          ),
          state('open',
            style({
              'margin-left': '250px'
            })
          ),
          transition('close => open', animate('250ms ease-in')),
          transition('open => close', animate('250ms ease-in')),
        ]),
    
        trigger('onPageReady', [
          state('inactive',
            style({
              opacity: 0.4
            })
          ),
          state('active',
            style({
              opacity: 1
            })
          ),
          transition('inactive => active', animate('250ms ease-in')),
          transition('active => inactive', animate('250ms ease-in')),
        ])
      ]
    })
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    
    
      /**
       * Get the sidenav state.
       */
      sideNavState: string = this.mediator.getSideNavState;
    
 
     
      constructor(
        private mediator: MediatorService,
      ) { }
    
      ngOnInit() {
    
    
        // Subscribe on changes important.
        this.mediator.sideNavListener.subscribe( state => {
          this.sideNavState = state;
        });
    
      }
    
    
    }
```

### mediator.service.ts

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
    
    
    @Injectable()
    export class MediatorService {
    
      APP_VERSION: String = 'v8.3.1.36';
    
      // default value.
      // this variable track the value between sessions.
      private _sideState: any = 'open';
    
      /** This is the mini variant solution with animations trick. */
      sideNavListener: any = new Subject();
    
      get sideNavState() {
        return this._sideState;
      }
    
      setSidenavState(state) {
        this._sideState = state;
      }
    
    
      constructor() {
    
        this.sideNavListener.subscribe( state => {
          this.setSidenavState(state);
        });
      
    
      }
    
    
    }
```

### menu-left.component.html

```html
    <div class="sidenav_menu_left" 
        [@onSideNavChange]="sideNavState" 
        style="width:100%; height: 100vh;" 
        fxLayout="column" 
        [style.overflow]="overflowState">
    
        <p>Sidenav content left</p>
    
        <!-- this can toggle the sidenav -->
        <div fxFlex="100" (click)="toggleSideNav();" class="hoverble"></div>
    
    </div>
```

### menu-left.component.ts

```js
    import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
    import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material';
    import {trigger, state, style, transition, animate, keyframes, query, group} from '@angular/animations';
    
    
    // Mediator: the main service, later this service is gonna have more generic use.
    import { MediatorService } from '@app-services/mediator/mediator.service';
    import { delay } from 'q';
    
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-admin-menu-left',
      templateUrl: './admin-menu-left.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./admin-menu-left.component.css'],
      animations: [
    
        // animate sidenave
        trigger('onSideNavChange', [
          state('close',
            style({
              width: '60px'
            })
          ),
          state('open',
            style({
              width: '250px'
            })
          ),
          transition('close => open', animate('250ms ease-in')),
          transition('open => close', animate('250ms ease-in')),
    
        ])
    
      ]
    })
    export class MenuLeftComponent implements OnInit {
    
    
      /**
       * Get the sidenav state,
       */
      sideNavState: string = this.mediator.sideNavState;
    
    
      overflowState: any = 'auto';
    
      constructor(
        private mediator: MediatorService
      ) {
    
      }
    
      ngOnInit() {
    
        this.mediator.sideNavListener.subscribe( state => {
          this.sideNavState = state;
        });
    
      }
    
      /**
       * On animation done.
       * @param x
       */
      animationEvent(x) {
        this.overflowState = 'auto';
      }
    
      /**
       * Toggle the sidenave state.
       *
       * Hides entire sidenav onclose.
       */
      setSideNavState() {
        this.mediator.toggle().then( snap => {
          console.log(snap);
        });
      }
    
    
      /**
       * Toggle, Open or close the sidenav.
       *
       * Set the sidenave state on mediator.
       */
      toggleSideNav() {
    
        switch (this.sideNavState) {
    
          case 'close':
    
            this.sideNavState = 'open';
            this.mediator.setSideNavState(this.sideNavState);
    
            setTimeout( () => {{
              this.sideNavText      = this.sideNavText === 'open' ? 'close' : 'open';
              this.sideNavIcon      = this.sideNavIcon === 'open' ? 'close' : 'open';
              this.sideNavCopyRight = this.sideNavCopyRight === 'open' ? 'close' : 'open';
            }}, 200);
          break;
    
          case 'open':
            this.sideNavText      = this.sideNavText === 'open' ? 'close' : 'open';
            this.sideNavIcon      = this.sideNavIcon === 'open' ? 'close' : 'open';
            this.sideNavCopyRight = this.sideNavCopyRight === 'open' ? 'close' : 'open';
    
            setTimeout( () => {{
              this.sideNavState = this.sideNavState === 'open' ? 'close' : 'open';
              this.mediator.setSideNavState(this.sideNavState);
            }}, 200);
          break;
    
          default:
            console.log('#6644');
            break;
        }
    
        this.overflowState = 'hidden';
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to apply your solution but I find the problem that there are some unrecognized variables.
Do you have an example working?
Also it throws me this error: The provided animation trigger "onSideNavChangeC" has not been registered!

Comment: you must provide the correct animation name look again the `home.component.ts`

Comment: rename the "onSideNavChangeC" to `onSideNavChange`

Comment: sideNavState: any = this.mediator.sideNavState; 
it written in MenuLeftComponent but there no "sideNavState" in mediator service.
    this.mediator.toggle().then( snap => {
      console.log(snap);
    });
And "toggle()" as well not there

Comment: @Rahimjon Rustamov I will update the answer today, but before the update, I think you are missing some steps.

Comment: Please update it. It would be great. I checked and I found there are more errors in my code. Maybe versions have been changed in animations

Comment: @Rahimjon Rustamov I have added a stackblitz example

Comment: Hi, what If we want to close sidebar by default? I tried opened="false" . sidebar is hidden but there is it's space. how can we handle this? @GeorgeC.

Answer (score 6):

I have wrestled with this quite a bit.  The solution is much simpler then you might think...almost everything in angular can be animated and we can solve this problem with a few lines of very simple animation code...

in a file called sidenav.animations.ts
  You will create an animation to animate the width of the <mat-sidenav> between 200px and 60px

You will create a second animation to animate the <mat-sidenav-content> between having a margin-left of 201px and 61px.

**./sidenav.animations.ts**

```
 import {
  animate,
  state,
  style,
  transition,
  trigger,
} from '@angular/animations';

/*
 * animation: sideNaveAnimation
 * trigger: 'openClose'
 *
 * comments: sets the width of an element to 200px when 'open' and to 60px
 *   when closed.  Animates in between these two states over '0.3s'
 */

export const sideNavAnimation = trigger('openCloseSidenav', [
    // ...
    state('open', style({
      width: '200px',
    })),
    state('closed', style({
      width: '60px',
    })),
    transition('open <=> closed', [
      animate('0.3s')
    ]),
  ]);

/*
 * animation: sideNavContainerAnimation
 * trigger: 'openCloseSidenavContent'
 *
 * comments: Sets the margin-left to 201px when "open" and 61px when "closed".
 */

export const sideNavContainerAnimation = trigger('openCloseSidenavContent', [
    state('open', style({
      'margin-left': '201px',
    })),
    state('closed', style({
      'margin-left': '61px',
    })),
    transition('open <=> closed', [
      animate('0.3s')
    ]),
  ]);
```

in your app.component.ts...

You will import the two animations and use them in the animations array which will allow you to use the triggers as defined in sidenav.animations.ts ('openCloseSidenav' and 'openCloseSidenavContent') within your app.component.html

You will create a boolean (isOpen) to keep track of which state the sidenav is in

You will create a function called toggle() that will switch the variable isOpen between true and false. This function will be called from the press of a button in app.component.html

**./app.component.ts**
Don't forget to import your MatSidenavModule, MatButtonsModule, MatIconModule, MatListModule, and BrowserAnimationsModule into your app.module.ts as well or you won't be able to use <mat-sidenav> or any of that anywhere in your app.component.html

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

//...

import { sideNavAnimation, sideNavContainerAnimation } from './sidenav.animations';

//...


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  animations: [sideNavAnimation, sideNavContainerAnimation]
})

export class AppComponent {

  isOpen = true;

  toggle() {
     this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
   }

//...

}
```

and in your app.component.html...
  You will call toggle() with a button placed somewhere in the sidenav.

You will place the animation trigger: 'openCloseSidenav' on the <mat-sidenav> with an *expression* that will choose which of the two defined states ('open' or 'closed' as defined in sidenav.animations.ts) the element should be in and animate between the states based on the state of the variable isOpen.

You will place the animation trigger: 'openCloseSidenavContent' on the <mat-sidenav-content> with the same expression as above.

**./app.component.html**

```
<mat-sidenav-container>

  <mat-sidenav [@openCloseSidenav]="isOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'" mode="side" opened role="navigation">
    <mat-nav-list>
      <!-- Place nav links here -->

      <button type="button" aria-label="Toggle nav" mat-icon-button (click)="toggle()">
      <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>

    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content [@openCloseSidenavContent]="isOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>

</mat-sidenav-container>
```

You will have to fill in the rest yourself, my <mat-sidenav-list> has stuff as shown below in it.

...I am using the variable isOpen to decide if the text next to the icons should be displayed..I will soon either add in animations to the <mat-chip-list> tags to make those fade out when the toggle() is called and isOpen changes or I will shorten the animation time down to 0.0s so that it snaps instantly between the two states...

...this will however work as is even without the *ngIf="isOpen" in the tag...

```
    <a mat-list-item (click)="signOut()">
        <span  class="app-nav-list-icon">
          <mat-icon matListIcon class="app-nav-list-icon">
            <fa-icon icon="sign-out-alt"style="color: #808DE1;"></fa-icon>
          </mat-icon>
        </span>
        <mat-chip-list *ngIf="isOpen" style="padding-left: .5em;">
          <mat-chip>Logout</mat-chip>
        </mat-chip-list>
      </a>
```

...big take away here is that *simple* animations can be used to control the behavior and look of every aspect of your app...

visit https://angular.io/guide/animations for more details on exactly how this works...

Answer (score 3):

The original tracked by Angular Material:
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/1728

The material team released the specs for this behavior recently:
https://material.io/components/navigation-rail#behavior

Someone by the name of Jordan Hall already published a directive that will handle this for you:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-material-rail-drawer
Repo here https://github.com/Jordan-Hall/angular-material-rail-drawer-plugin

I'm about to use Jordans package in my own project. Will update with feedback if anyone asks.

Comment: Greg let me know if you face any issues. Im looking at the outstanding issue this weekend.

Comment: Works a treat! I'm using it in a basic scenario at the moment, no property binding on mode for media queries, that will come later as the site matures. I havent paid particularly close attention to animations, styling and cross browser compatibility yet as I'm still pre-alpha. Started using it with Angular 9.1.5 and did a --forced upgrade to Angular Material 10, still working.

Comment: Cheers for that feedback. I'm aiming to get out a release version soon. However, I've also started the work on getting this into main repo https://github.com/angular/components/pull/20050

Comment: Be aware that the NPM package doesn't support [Swap between Rail, Full or Hidden modes](https://github.com/Jordan-Hall/angular-material-rail-drawer-plugin/issues/26)

Comment: This appears to not be supporting in Angular 12. (See)[https://github.com/Jordan-Hall/angular-material-rail-drawer-plugin/issues/44]

Answer (score 2):

You have to put in the header the property "autosize"

```html
 <mat-sidenav-container autosize >
```

with this property the content adjust to the menu's width

Comment: nop is not working I have tried.This question is very old. I solve this with angular animations. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Would you be so kind as to provide your animations solution, @George?

Comment: @LarsGyrupBrinkNielsen let me know if this helps you. I added my solution

Answer (score 2):

Using typescript code you can update the width of sidebar like this :

```
toggleSideBar(){
    // console.log('toggle called');
    // this.sb.toggle();
    if(this.widthSideBar == this.widthSideBarExpanded){
      this.widthSideBar = this.widthSideBarCollapsed;
    }
    else{
      this.widthSideBar = this.widthSideBarExpanded;
    }
    // snav.toggle();
  }
```

and the corresponding html file will look like

```
..
<mat-sidenav [style.width.px]="widthSideBar">..</mat-sidenav>
..
<mat-sidenav-content [style.marginLeft.px]="widthSideBar">..</mat-sidenav-content>
..
```

Here I have set the width and margin-left of the content to adjust dynamically.